# Are blanched tomatoes safe to eat if left out for 8 hrs then refrigerated for 5 hours.

Tags: food-safety, tomatoes

I started to blanch tomatoes then had to leave for an emergency. About half the batch was peeled & the rest blanched but unpeeled. Sat on counter for about 8 hours. When i got home i put the peeled ones in the fridge for 5 hrs & left the others out all night. Some of the blanched tomatoes had bruises. Are all of them OK to continue using for soup or should i toss all & start over?

Comment: Blanching does very little to stop bacteria action, it is primarily to stop enzyme action which will cause natural decay of vegetation, and in this case make peeling easier. Raw tomatoes on the counter for 13 hours are fine, but you have heated them so changed the equation.  They still have their skin, but have gone higher into the temperature danger zone of high bacterial growth rate. I guess an important question is did you ice water quench them and get the temps down after blanching? I think the bruising might be the clincher for me that would push me to discard.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be on the safe side, 8 hours is a long time to stand.

I would discard them all and start over.